# jQuery / Javascript Conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to web developing, but I believe I have a conflict with my jQuery / javascripts (am not entirely sure which one). My site has a drop-down menu and an image selector. When both scripts are in there together they will not work. Whichever one comes first, is overide by the latter. I believe the 2 scripts that are actually causing the problem are "js/jquery-1.js" and "js/global-perf-minified.js" but here are all the scripts being used within my page:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/product.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/searchsuggest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_004.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="css/colorbox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/jquery_007.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="js/cloud-zoom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/cloud-zoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utag_008.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

<script src="js/global-perf-minified.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/product-minified.js"></script>
```

I saw some posts about adding a '.noconflict()' style but didn't seem to have much luck. I am willing to accept that I could just be inserting it wrong / picking up the wrong code for this. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Well, you appear to be loading jQuery at least twice (`js/jquery-1.js`, `js/jquery.js`) if not three times (`js/jquery-1.js`, `js/jquery.js`, `js/jquery_007.js`). Just include it *once*.

Comment: How many versions of jQuery do you need?

Comment: do you have a link to the site?

Comment: I have taken out all other versions of jQuery except 'js/jquery-1.js' because if I do this it gives me the error 'app is underfined' followed by 'app namespace is not loaded yet!'

Comment: Even without the others though it still doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, I have removed duplicates and seemed to resolve the 'app is underfined' error by using '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>' instead. This is now the only jQuery script in my code. But, I still can't get both assets to work.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicates:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_004.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_004.js"></script>
```

Declaring jquery many times....better check those and see if they are duplicates ;)

-----------------EDIT---------------------------

Now your code should looks like, with just one jquery:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/product.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/searchsuggest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="css/colorbox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="js/cloud-zoom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="js/cloud-zoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utag_008.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

    <script src="js/global-perf-minified.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/product-minified.js"></script>
```

If you keep with problems then try putting just, two or three js, like this:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
```

If works with this two, then adding the others until you find the one that is creating bugs or problems(conflicts) with the rest of your js ;)

Saludos.

Comment: Thank you. I have removed duplicates but still no luck!

Comment: You have now jquery included only one time in your code....but the error keeps follow, or is another error??....may be you have in the rest of the js, functions qith the same name or somthing similar....show me the full error message

Comment: No error messages now. I just can't get both scripts working at the same time. Whatever Javascript come first seems to be the one that rules.

Comment: Thank you. I know which one is causing the problem for my drop-down menu, it is '<script src="js/global-perf-minified.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> but if I don't include this one than my other image-select function doesn't work.

Comment: Try changing the function name in the js, and the way to invoque the function ;)

Comment: hmm, how do you do that? Sorry - newbie here! :)

Comment: It's not hard to do....open your js, see the structure, find the conflict, change the line, or change the function name on the js...and the way of calling the function menu....so if your function menu it's called "dropotron" in the js change the dropotron name by "dropmenu_js" and call it by that name

Comment: Thank you for your help. Am still struggling to find the conflict - the coding is HUGE and I can't seem to find an easy way of finding 2 things that match. Obviously there's a lot of things that match up, such as 'hover' 'mouseover' etc, but i'm not entirely sure what i'm looking for! Sorry! Very new to this...

Comment: You include this right: <script src="js/global-perf-minified.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>  ....you say this js is the one that alloes you to make a drop down menu....now, how you build your menu...or post your page or site ;)